# ArangoDB start failing in centos6

Tags: centos6, arangodb

ArangoDB start in failing with the following error in centos6. I'm using latest arangodb version **arangodb3-3.3.16-1.x86_64.rpm**

[root@vm1 RPM]# service arangodb3 start
*Starting /usr/sbin/arangod: : arena 0 background thread creation failed (13)
/etc/init.d/arangodb3: line 43:  3576 Segmentation fault      $ARANGO_BIN --uid arangodb --gid arangodb --server.rest-server false --log.foreground-tty false --database.check-version
FATAL ERROR: EXIT_CODE_RESOLVING_FAILED for code 139 - could not resolve exit code 139*
[root@vm1 RPM]#

Any help will be really appreciable.

Comment: How big is your machine? The error message "arena 0 background thread creation failed (13)" from JEMalloc seems to indicate that you hit some limit.

Answer (score 0):

The exit code 139 = 128 + 11 means that the Arangod process crashed with a segmentation violation

Can you try the following:

- Check your server for a faulty memory bank
- Run a memory test with memtester

This should fix the problem

There was a similar issue that has been raised on GitHub: https://github.com/arangodb/arangodb/issues/2329